# 'Unrecognized in environments' error into browser with vue-cli-service serve project vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have a project with vue.js 2 technology.

This project runs into docker environment.

I would like to install debugging system for this project. For that I need to install 'local' (without docker) environment with npm, node, vue-cli, node_modules, etc.... All this tools seems to be correct installed.

Now I launch this command for launching my application into my web browser :

```
vue-cli-service serve
```

Compil source and copy seems to be good and It give me url for open into my browser

```
Local:   http://localhost:8082/
```

When I click on this url my browser launch page with empty content (white page) and my inspector browser tell me that :

```
Error: URL (http://localhost:8082/) Unrecognized in environments
```

For you, why I have this error and what the issue from ? (server npm, compilation of code, ...)

**Technical informations :**

*npm : 6.13.4*

*node : 12.14.1*

*vue-cli : @vue/cli 4.3.1*

Comment: If you are serving it on docker container you need to use Nginx server to host your dist localhost is not available in a docker environment
Read [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html)

Comment: I don't serve it on docker container like as writing on my question